# How to downgrade glibc on Arch Linux?

Tags: glibc, archlinux

After upgrading the system using :

```
sudo pacman -Syu
```

all browsers' tabs start crashing, I have faced this problem before and I solved it by downgrading the glibc package. but now I am trying to do it again, but I get :

```
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: installing glibc (2.30-3) breaks dependency 'glibc=2.31' required by lib32-glibc
```

is my problem now with lib32-glib ? solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

just removed lib32-glibc and it worked

Answer (score 0):

with `pacman -Rcns my-package` a lib can be removed with its dependancies

- **-c** for changelog (get chatty)
- **-n** for native (where you search for the package)
- **-s** for search (will actually cascade into dependancies)

It is also possible to search the faulty package by `pacman -Q my-package` against `pacman -Qs my-package` to see if an upgrade is possible. A rollback is of course possible if no update is solving the issue.

glic (not lib32) is a rather sensitive package so I wouldn't remove it. And it has a bunch of sensitive dependancies too.

((I have faced the issue with *glibc version 2.34* and hopefully the update has fixed an issue))